# Filtered features in attribute table

Tags: qgis, layers, filter, table, remove

Attribute table header of point layer says: "Features total 1200, Filtered: 1197, Selected: 0"

There is no layer filter active and also no filter is set in the layer properties under tab "source".

How can I remove the filter?

EDIT: I am actually not "missing" any features. All features I'd expect to be visible and listed in the attribute table are actually there. So the number of "filtered" features is correct. The number of "features total" is what is actually wrong or at least confusing. The layer was created by merging two vector layers with the merge function of the toolkit. However, the strange filtering subject seems to appear at a later stage of data management. I have a second point layer with a different data set that shows the same problem. "Features total: 1973, filtered: 1102, selected: 0".

Comment: Have you maybe set the attribute table so it only shows the features within the current map frame?

Comment: @Erik no. when I zoom out completely it's still the same

Comment: @Hannes: can you share a sample dataset?

Comment: @ThomasB yeah I could do that. But how?

Comment: @Thomas B  please see my edit in the original post

Comment: if the layer has a spatial index you could delete/recreate it.

Comment: @ThomasB the layer has no spatial index

Comment: If you have dropbox/gdrive or something like that you could upload your testdata and send the link. otherwise I could still only guess: perhaps invalid geometries (-->check geometry validity algorithm).  you could also export the layer as geopackage and compare the two layers.

Comment: here is a sample data set. I exported the original layer as a new shape file. Obviously the problem with the new data set does not exist, as only the filtered objects of the original file are exported. Will say: now the attribute tables number of "total" and "filtered" features is the same. Anyway, it may help to find something?! https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6ni3l9atjuua9sh/AAA4dfWOZieVK_MjiPhO42DNa?dl=0

Comment: no, this exported dataset looks totally fine but the structure is pretty sure not the same as your original sample dataset as the new shapefile get's created "from scratch" during the export. So if there's perhaps an inconsistence between the shp/dbf/shx-files in the old dataset you won't find this inconsistence after exporting it as a new dataset.

Comment: ah ok. my fault. but I wanted to avoid to share the original file as it contains data that I don't want to be accessed by anyone. how could I solve that?